# Batch to move files based on a common prefix

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder with many files, most are file type `.nib` with some being `.m3u` files.

I want to create a folder for each m3u file with the same folder name as the m3u, and then move the m3u file as well as any nib file that starts by the full m3u name in that folder.

I tried to write a batch command but it only created the folder and moved the m3u but not the nib files sharing its prefix.

Here is what I have:

```bash
for %%i in (*.m3u*) do md "%%~ni" & move "%%i" "%%~ni" & move "%%i*.nib" "%%~ni"
```

I think the problem is with the syntax of `%%i*.nib`, I need something to convey any file that starts with the full name of that m3u, followed by an unknown number of characters, then extension nib.

Could someone please help?

Comment: `for %%i in ("*.m3u") do md "%%~ni" & move "%%~i" "%%~ni" & move "%%~ni*.nib" "%%~ni"`?

Comment: The first advice is stop trying to place multiple commands unnecessarily onto one line, in a script. Parenthesize the `do` portion and use seperate lines for each individial command. If you don't want to do that, please change the first ampersand to `&&`, and see what happens if you change `%%i*.nib` to `%%~ni*.nib`.